# how to generate a pdf file with VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, pdf

i would like to generate a very simple report with some images and text and i am wondering if there is a way to generate a pdf file with vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756127/building-pdf-files-with-c) SO question. It pertains to C# but since the libraries are .net compat..you should be ok

UPDATE
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/ and 
http://www.pdf-technologies.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can export to a PDF file using a Crystal Reports object, which comes packaged with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

The PDFSharp library (http://pdfsharp.com/) is something I used recently in a C# project. There are a lot of advanced features but fortunately you can start with just a few basic commands. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Word can export as pdf:

```
    Dim doc As Word.Document = New Word.Document()
    doc.Content.Text = "Hello World"
    doc.ExportAsFixedFormat("C:\mypath\myfilename.pdf", Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF)
    doc.Close(False)
```

Comment: Works fine. Remember to add references to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word  Then in your project import Microsoft.Office.Interop : Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Answer (score 1):

Use MicrosoftReportViewer from the Toolbox.

Comment: where can i find it? i dont see it

Comment: yes it is - I've used it.   It can export data to Excel and PDF files.